# Nginx Unicode characters in local folder path = 500 "Internal Server Error"

Tags: nginx

I have the following config setup:

```
   server {
        listen              8000;
        server_name         localhost;
        access_log          logs/access.log combined buffer=32M flush=15m;
        root                html/src;
        index               index.html index.htm;

        location / {

            access_log      off;
        }

        location ~ /(files|list|img)/ {
            alias           file_server$uri;
            autoindex       on;
            autoindex_format html;
        }
    }
```

It work just fine as long as I don't have any åäöÅÄÖ in the local file path... If I try to browse to a folder or file with any of those characters the server will respond with a 500 error. The error log states: `1113: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page`.

So my question is, how do I configure the server to understand unicode characters?

**EDIT**: it seems like the `autoindex` is at fault here...

Comment: I don't have direct experience with this, so leaving as a comment that `nginx` usually includes the [`ngx_http_charset_module`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_charset_module.html) which I *think* has what you are looking for, unless this is an OS level issue.

Comment: It seems like the fault is the `autoindex` which is listing files with not utf-8 it seems. Removing that and I can fetch filenames and url's with escaped characters.

Comment: Might be worth reporting to the nginx project.

Comment: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/2175#ticket

Comment: Ticket closed, referred to the original ticket https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/458 opened 7 years ago :)

Comment: Interestingly, the bug's [second comment](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/458#comment:2) states "I forgot to mention than[sic] behavior of autoindex module depends on selected charset. The patch does work with 'charset utf-8' directive in config file, but probably will give inconsistent results with other settings." Not to brag or anything, but that was my first comment. (o;